# Delete segment in url rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm really stuck on a 301 rewrite rule, actually i've got a rule like this :

```
http://www.example.com/search/continent/country/name-of-country/
```

I would like to rewrite to this :

```
http://www.example.com/my-search/continent/name-of-country/
```

So get rid of the "/country/" segment
I tried :

```
RewriteRule ^search/([^/]+)/country/([^/]+)/$ http://www.example.com/my-search/$1/$2/ [R=301,L]
```

But it's not working, it rewrites :

```
http://www.example.com/my-search/continent/country/name-of-country/
```

Help would be very appreciated.

Comment: Have you cleared your browser's cache?

Comment: Yes and I tried with multiple browsers to be sure, it's stuck with this segment.

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any other rules that are redirecting or scripts that are redirecting? That rule looks fine.

Comment: You were right, another rule was overriding this one. I deactivated all and tested all of them one by one and this one is actually working. My issue is elsewhere then ...